# TypeError: r is not a function - next.js

Tags: javascript, backend, typeerror, next.js14

I am trying to use a const from a context in my server side, inside `/api`. But when I use this, my backend console returns:

> TypeError: r is not a function

and

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

in the request that, without the context, works perfectly.

I also checked the variable before using it and it is returning the string it should. How to solve this?

```js
'use client'
import { calendarInsertContext } from './calendarInsertContext'

export async function GET(req) {
  const { sdr } = useContext(calendarInsertContext)
  console.log('sdr backend: ', sdr)
```

Comment: please provide the code where you have created context so that it will be more clear in debugging!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'next-auth' latest(beta) version it's happen, so downgrade 'next-auth' with stable version it would be resolved.

For more info - Follow this [issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/9251)

Comment: Link could die, making your answer less useful with time. You could improve this answer by documenting the steps OP needs to take in order to downgrade next-auth.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error,
apparently i had used **'use client'** in my **route.ts** file which was **not required.**

it got resolved.
it seems that **vs-code** will not throw any **error indicator** in file whether we use 'use client' in a file or not.